# my flutter build ipa fail with profile on vs code

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I try to do flutter build ipa and I received this error:

> Error (Xcode): No profiles for 'com.example.middeyapp' were found:
> Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles
> matching 'com.example.middeyapp'. Automatic signing is disabled and
> unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass
> -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.

For context, that is not the real build id of the app.

I have created an Identifier already for the app and I still receive this error, I was given an enrolled account to login on my Xcode butI don’t why I'm still receiving this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check this:

1. Open Runner.xcodeproj in the XCode (ios) folder.
2. Check that these fields filled:

[image]

Comment: Mine is not showing anything on the "Signing Certificate Apple Development" how can I let it show?

Comment: Do you registered the Apple Developer account and paid for it?

Comment: I did not on my own account, I was given a friend account details to login and push the app to apptore store

Comment: Try to open "Team" -> "Add an account" and sign in.

Comment: But I think it's a bad idea, you as developer need to have your own Apple account and your friend can add you as developer to the team.
I think it’s illegal as well.

Comment: So, if our Developer account is unpaid, can we still build and push?

Comment: Dear @HrithikTiwari I don't know about it (because my account every time active), I think, you can build it, but don't push it to Apple.